# Send message to channels when application is deployed

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to display a 'New version available, please refresh page' message to all my users when I deploy a new version of my app.

I'm thinking if there was a way to run some code, after a new version is deployed, then I could use that to publish to the channels.

Is this possible?

Comment: How about your applications `start/2` function? It should be in `lib/my_app.ex`.

Comment: What about your deployment tool? May be you could execute an "after deploy"-recipe, which broadcasts such a message.